# Pandas update values of multiple rows of a column based on values of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like:

> ```
>  column1  column2
>    a        32
>    b       175
>    b       165
>    a        80
> ```

and I want to update the value (multiplied by 10) of every row of column2 whose value in column1 == 'a'. The result is expected to be like:

> ```
>  column1  column2
>    a       320
>    b       175
>    b       165
>    a       800
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very short with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['column1']=='a', 'column2'] *= 10
```

You get:

```
  column1  column2
0       a      320
1       b      175
2       b      165
3       a      800
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `np.where`

```py
df['column2'] = np.where(df['column1'].eq('a'), df['column2'].mul(10), df['column2'])
```

Or `df.mask`

```py
df['column2'] = df['column2'].mask(df['column1'].eq('a'), df['column2'].mul(10))
```

```
  column1  column2
0       a      320
1       b      175
2       b      165
3       a      800
```